# How do I check a form is a node type form?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

I am writing a custom module and I want to add some condition in `hook_form_alter()` to check the form is a node type form.

Is there any function to check whether a form is for a node?

Answer (score 3):

In the case you are referring to the node edit form (the form that allows you to edit a node), instead of `hook_form_alter()`, you need to implement [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), which is a specific implementation of `hook_form_alter()` used when you know the form ID of the base form. In your case, you need to implement `hook_form_node_form_alter()` exactly how the Book module does with [`book_form_node_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_form_node_form_alter/7).

```
function book_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form['#node'];

  // Omissis.
}
```

`$form['#node']` is set by [`node_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7.x), which contains the following code. (Note the comment, which says that `$form['#node']` is going to be removed in Drupal 8, and that modules should instead use `$form_state['node']`.)

```php
// @todo D8: Remove. Modules should access the node using $form_state['node'].
$form['#node'] = $node;
```

In the case you are referring to the form you find at admin/structure/types/manage and that allows you to edit the properties of a content type, you need to implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, which a specific implementation of `hook_form_alter()` done for a specific form ID, which in this case is *node_type*. This is what does the Comment module with [`comment_form_node_type_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_form_node_type_form_alter/7). If you need to know the content type for which the form is shown, you can use `$form['#node_type']->type`.

Comment: It looks like $form['#node'] no longer works.
  use `$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();`

Comment: `$form['#node']` is still used from Drupal 7. Drupal 8 or higher versions don't set it anymore; with those versions, and for entity forms, `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()` returns the entity object associated with the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_node_form_alter`.

Example:

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $type = $form['#node']->type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

d8/d9

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeForm;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function <module_name>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  $isNodeForm = $form_object instanceof NodeForm;
  if ($isNodeForm) {
    ...
  }
}
```